# Power BI Advanced Editor how to get Text of SelectedRow?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m, powerbi-datasource

I'm new to Power BI, have been testing trying to fetch data from an API and have done so with a little success.  One of the calls I've been playing around with will take a begin and end date as well as a comma separated list of ids in the body of the call and will return information about each id.  I'm struggling with the comma separated list a little.  I have a query that creates the comma separated list, it ends up being a 1 record table with this comma separated value.  I am using `Text.Combine` to concatenate the body parameters, but when I try to concatenate the comma separated values I get the message "`Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Text.`"  I have a variable, `#"Filtered Rows"`, set to `Table.SelectRows(#"Extracted Values", each ([Index] = 1))` and am trying to concatenate this in `Text.Combine`.  Ok, it's a table and it can't be concatenated to a string.  How do I get the value of the selected row as text so that it may be concatenated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Text.Combine` function expects a list as its first argument.

Fortunately, specifying `TableName[RowName]` gives a list so that you can write the following:

```
Text.Combine(#"Filtered Rows"[ColumnYouWantToCombine], ",")
```